# Where can I find messaging-simulator.apk?

Tags: android, apk

In order to test auto apps, docs say that,

Install the Android Messaging simulator (messaging-simulator.apk) on the test device. You can do this using the adb command line tool.

But, where do I get messaging-simulator.apk from? Is it my test app I have created? But, in the next statement it says -

Install your app on the test device.

So how do I go ahead with this?

Comment: does it mean its my own app??

Comment: I don't think you have read it completely : https://developer.android.com/training/auto/start/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the complete path of this apk, but Documentation says that "**To get the simulators, open the SDK Manager and download them from Extras > Android Auto API Simulators.**"

So when you download any thing from *extra section*, these files will being saved into `<sdk-dir>/extras/`. So it would be a correct choice to search into `android` or `google` dir inside `<sdk>/extras/`, I am sure that you can get both apks *media-browser-simulator.apk* and *messaging-simulator.apk* from there.

Comment: @Smitha Most welcome. Plz update relative path of apks.

Answer (score 0):

simulator apks are present in this folder : Android_SDK\extras\google\simulators

Comment: On a Mac it will generally be: ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/simulators/